# Extending CommonViewModel to include additional properties

Tags: c#, custom-view, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I have a very simple problem: Depending on what environment I deploy Identity Server 3, I want to have the logon page to display a different image. The image source location is defined in the `web.config` and transformed depending on build configuration.

I'm overriding the partial `_login.html` to allow the image to be displayed, but I cannot find out how to (easily) pass into the view a variable that defines this configuration variable.

I believe that this is possible by using a `CustomViewService` shown here : http://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docs/advanced/customizingViews.html But I would like to know whether there is an easier way of passing a variable into a view without having to create a `CustomViewService`.

Would it be possible to extend the `CommonViewModel` and get Identity Server 3 to resolve this at run time ? The `ExtendedCommonViewModel` would be extremely simple :

```
public class ExtendedCommonViewModel : CommonViewModel
{
  public string ImageLocation
  {
     get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageLocation"].ToString(); }
  }
}
```

And then use it in the `_login.html` view as `<img src="{ImageLocation}" />`

I realise that this would still need to be parsed into the `Replace` function in the default view service, and so this is where this idea falls down : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Services/DefaultViewService/DefaultViewService.cs

So to reiterate; Is there an easy way to pass a variable into an overridden partial view in Identity Server 3 without having to create a `CustomViewService` ?

**Edit :**

Additional - I can see a hack of a solution by passing the variable in as a `Scripts` parameter on the `DefaultViewServiceOptions` but this seems too hacky.

Would is be possible to extend the `DefaultViewServiceOptions` and add a custom dictionary that can contain custom model parameters that could then be used in the view. This seems like the best solution, but would mean changing the `DefaultViewService`

Answer (score 0):

You're best off creating your own `IViewService` implementation.

It's possible to inherit the `DefaultViewService` and only override what you need to change.

In your case, I think you can just create a `CustomLoginViewModel` inheriting from `LoginViewModel` with whatever data you need.

```
public class CustomViewService : DefaultViewService 
{
   ...    
    public override Task<Stream> Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
    {
        var customVm = new CustomViewModel { MyProp = "123" };
        return Render(customVm, LoginView);
    }
}
```